# Animate children when hover at parent with Framer-motion

Tags: reactjs, web-animations, react-animations, framer-motion

Using framer motion I want to animate my Icon component to rotate 90 degrees when hovering at the parent element which is a button.

```js
<motion.button type="button" whileHover={{scale: 1.1}}>
    Visit our Industry 
    {/*Animate this Icon to rotate 90 degrees*/}
    <Icon type="arrow-up" /> 
</motion.button>
```

I saw the use of variants but not sure how to really use them with props like `whileHover`.

Any help will be appreciated since this is a new thing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to set 'whileHover' to a string and use the varients to animate.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-wozniak-2z01b

Comment: that's supper handy. Why this is not marked as answer?

Comment: You just saved my bacon on a really annoying jank bug I've been fighting for the last 2 days. lol

Answer (score 4):

Framer motion has **variants** that you can use to achieve this.

Link to documentation: [Documentation](https://www.framer.com/motion/animation/#variants)

Here is how you would make the arrow rotate and scale, while hovering a button:

```
const arrow = {
  initial: { rotate: 0, scale: 1 },
  animate: { rotate: 90, scale: 1.5 },
}

<motion.button
  initial="initial"
  animate="initial"
  whileHover="animate"
  style={{ flexDirection: "row", display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}
>
  <div style={{marginRight: 5}}>Visit our Industry</div>
  <motion.div variants={arrow}>↑</motion.div>
</motion.button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tho The first answer is very sufficient enough, here is some concept from the doc:

> **Propagation** :
> If a motion component has children, changes in variant will flow down through the component hierarchy. These changes in variant will flow down until a child component defines its own animate property.

So that means by default child motion components will inherit the parent variant and act as the same, until you specify their own.

But also note that if you set one variant (say `initial`) in those child components, The others will **stop** inheriting any variant and become `undefined`, meaning you have to specify their variants too.

Check out the doc: [PROPAGATION](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/animation/#propagation)